# How to extract multiple tables from multiple pages of a PDF and put them all in one DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-camelot

I want to put all tables of a PDF into a single DataFrame and the tables to have the same columns.

```
ka1 = camelot.read_pdf(r"example.pdf",'all')

for i,table in enumerate(ka1):
 v = table.df
 w = pd.concat(v)

print(w)
```

Comment: What is the error/issue that you are having with your code?

Comment: type error at concat

Comment: Post the actual, full error text in the question itself. Your code tries to concatenate a single dataframe though, v. `concat` works on multiple dataframes, not a single one. If you wanted to concatenate dataframes in a loop, use `w=pd.concat(w,v)`

Comment: TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"

Answer (score 2):

pandas.concat() expects a list of DataFrames. You could add all the DataFrames to a list in the for loop and concat them afterwards. For example:

```
ka1 = camelot.read_pdf(r"example.pdf",'all')

v = []
for i,table in enumerate(ka1):
    v.append(table.df)
w = pd.concat(v)

print(w)
```